# Storing and Accessing Methods from the AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, delegates, uipickerview

I am new in iPhone Development. I have a method that requires input from one .m class and uses the information in another .m file. I heard that if you store the variables and the methods in the appdelegate you can access the information. How can I do that? Also, how can I have user store a number from a UIPickerView as a integer as a variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing basic data you can do this simply using [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
//Setting an int
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:10 forKey:@"PICKER_VALUE"];
//Retreiving an int
int picker_value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PICKER_VALUE"];
```

For more advanced data storage [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is a good option.

Now while app delegates are a quick and dirty way to share data across the app you should avoid this approach in production apps (read all apps). [Cocoa with Love has an article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) about sharing top level data in the application.

> Relying on your AppDelegate object to manage your global variables can
>   quickly get scary for the same reason that global variables in general
>   are considered scary: you can easily put too much into this top level
>   and it becomes a big, unstructured mess. This problem is an
>   anti-pattern, often called the [Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).

Comment: Yes, but how can I store methods there or have the user store variables there?

Comment: Yes you are right! :) I have updated my answer to actually answer all of your question. The NSUserDefaults allows strings, numbers, BOOLs, arrays of those things and dictionaries of those as well.