# NSObject with +(NSArray)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsobject

I am creating a NSObject to load the TimeLine twitter
Code:

```
+ (NSArray *)executeTweetFetch

{

    __block NSArray *fetchedTweets = [NSArray array];

    NSURL *getTweetUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];



    SLRequest *tweetRequest  = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter

                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET

                                                            URL:getTweetUrl

                                                     parameters:nil];
    tweetRequest.account = ACAccount HERE!!!;

    [tweetRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            // Parse the responseData, which we asked to be in JSON format for this request, into an NSDictionary using NSJSONSerialization.

            NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
            fetchedTweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
            //At this point, fetchedTweet seems working fine, it gets the array send back.
        }
    }];

    return fetchedTweets;

}
```

...is Ok...but I have to add a ACAccount (another view). and since it is a + (NSArray *) it does not recognize my (ACAccount) or any object outside

Comment: What does "I have to add a ACAccount (another view)" mean?

Comment: edited....the user select a account in other view(TableView)

Comment: Why don't you add another parameter: `+ (NSArray *)executeTweetFetchForAccount:(ACAccount *)account`? - But your code has another big problem: `performRequestWithHandler` is an *asynchronous* function, which means that the block is not executed immediately, but later, when the request is done. Therefore `fetchedTweets` will always be an empty array when the function returns.

Comment: works like this: UITableviewController1(select account) -> NSObject(this,add account in "ACAccount HERE!!!") -> UITableviewController2(call NSObject and get fetchedTweets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Synchroneity

Before getting into the issue that you're asking about, it's well worth discussing what @MartinR mentioned at greater length:  The method `-[ACAccount performRequestWithHandler:]` is asynchronous.

Calling the method from the thread that code is being executed on results in some activity starting up on a second background [queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).  Meanwhile, execution continues on the first thread (the thread that is executing `performRequestWithHandler:` and `executeTweetRequest`).  Some indeterminate amount of time after `executeTweetRequest` is called, the block passed as the only argument to `-[ACAccount performRequestWithHandler:]` is called.

Consequently, you will not be able to synchronously return the array of tweets from `executeTweetRequest`.

The most stylish approach would be to change your method to be block based:

```
+ (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block
{
    NSURL *getTweetUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];
    SLRequest *tweetRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                 requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                           URL:getTweetUrl
                                                    parameters:nil];
    tweetRequest.account = //...this will be addressed in a moment
    [tweetRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
            NSArray *fetchedTweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
            block(fetchedTweets, jsonParsingError);
        }
    }];
}
```

When calling `fetchTweetsWithCompletion:` from your second `UITableViewController` subclass, you will pass in a block probably much like the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    [TwitterWrapper fetchTweetsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
        if (tweets) {
            self.tweets = tweets;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (error) {
            //present a UIAlertView, perhaps...
        }
    }];
    //...
}
```

The result of this code is that once the fetch of the tweets on a background queue has completed, your table view controller's property `tweets` will be set to the fetched result and its table view will reload its data.

## Scope (Addressing The Question)

The issue that you're describing

> since it is a + (NSArray *) it does not recognize my (ACAccount) or any object outside

is that you're unable to access the instance variables of any of the instances of your class (I'm going to call it `TwitterWrapper` for convenience) from within your class method `+[TwitterWrapper executeTweetFetch]`.  The problem here is one of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).  (As a result, thanks to [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting), the problem is also one of memory management.)

Our goal is to stash an instance of `ACAccount` somewhere from your first table view controller and access that instance from your second table view controller.

There are several ways of doing this:

### Use A Global Variable

The **worst** [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081703/1052673) is to a use a dreaded [global variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#C_and_C.2B.2B):

In `TwitterWrapper.h`, you would declare `extern` the `ACAccount` for twitter:

```
//TwitterWrapper.h

extern ACAccount *twitterAccount;

@interface TwitterWrapper : executeTweetFetch
+ (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block;
@end
```

In `TwitterWrapper.m`, you would define `twitterAccount` so that it has global scope (for example, prior to the `@implementation` block:

```
ACAccount *twitterAccount;

@implementation TwitterWrapper
//...
@end
```

And in the definition of your class method `executeTweetFetch` you would have

```
+ (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block
{
    //...
    tweetRequest.account = twitterAccount;
    //...
}
```

**NOTE**: This approach is very unstylish, not to mention outright dangerous.  [Global variables should be avoided whenever possible.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)  Avoiding one is certainly possible in this case.

---

The next two approaches both involve changing `fetchTweetsWithCompletion:` into an instance method and adding an `ACAccount` property to `TwitterWrapper`.  The class' `@interface` will look like

```
@interface TwitterWrapper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) ACAccount *account;
- (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block;
@end
```

The `@implementation` will look like

```
@implementation TwitterWrapper

- (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block
{
    //...
    twitterRequest.account = self.account;
    //...
}

@end
```

### Use A Shared Instance

The second worst approach in this case is to use a shared instance of `TwitterWrapper`.  This involves adding a class method (called something clever like `+sharedWrapper`) to the class:

```
@interface TwitterWrapper : NSObject
+ (TwitterWrapper *)sharedWrapper;
@property (nonatomic) ACAccount *account;
- (void)fetchTweetsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block;
@end
```

and using [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)'s [`dispatch_once`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once) to initialize a [`static` local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables):

```
@implementation TwitterWrapper

//...

+ (TwitterWrapper *)sharedWrapper
{
    static TwitterWrapper *sharedWrapper = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ 
        sharedWrapper = [[self alloc] init]; 
    });

    return sharedWrapper;
}

//...

@end
```

At this point, you have an instance of `TwitterWrapper` into which you can store the instance of `ACAccount` from your first table view controller and make use of (via `self.account` within the implementation of `-fetchTweetsWithCompletion:`) from your second table view controller:

Somewhere within your first `UITableViewController` subclass you would have

```
//...
ACAccount *theAccount = //this is initialized somehow within this class (the first UITableViewController subclass), probably by the selection of a row
[[TwitterWrapper sharedWrapper] setAccount:theAccount];
//...
```

Then, within your second `UITableViewController` subclass (probably within `-viewDidLoad`), you would have

```
    //...
    [[TwitterWrapper sharedWrapper] fetchTweetsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
        if (tweets) {
            self.tweets = tweets;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (error) {
            //present a UIAlertView, perhaps...
        }
    }];
    //...
```

This solution, however, is very similar to using a global variable.  (The difference is that the creation of the global variable will be thread safe.)

### Pass An Instance Of TwitterWrapper

A much better solution is to pass an instance of `TwitterWrapper` from your first table view controller to your second.

**NOTE**: For brevity, I will assume that the second table view controller becomes active immediately after the user selects an account row in the first table view controller.

To do this, you will need to add a property

```
@property (nonatomic) TwitterWrapper *twitterWrapper;
```

to your second `UITableViewController` subclass.

Somewhere within your first table view controller you would have

```
//...
ACAccount *theAccount = //this is initialized somehow within this class (the first UITableViewController subclass), probably by the selection of a row
TwitterWrapper *theTwitterWrapper = [[TwitterWrapper alloc] init];
twitterWrapper.account = theAccount;
SecondTableViewController *tweetsTableViewController = //initialize the table view controller
tweetsTableViewController.twitterWrapper = theTwitterWrapper;
//...
```

Then, within your second `UITableViewController` subclass (probably within `-viewDidLoad`), you would have

```
    //...
    [self.twitterWrapper fetchTweetsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
        if (tweets) {
            self.tweets = tweets;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (error) {
            //present a UIAlertView, perhaps...
        }
    }];
    //...
```

### Pass An Instance Of ACAccount

Rather than storing an instance of `TwitterWrapper` on your second `UITableViewController` subclass instance, the best solution is to store an instance of `ACAccount` and alter `TwitterWrapper`'s interface for fetching tweets once again.

In this case, we'll want the fetch method to again be a class method.  As @MartinR suggested, add an account parameter to your fetch method:

```
+ (void)fetchTweetsWithAccount:(ACAccount *)theAccount completion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block
{
    NSURL *getTweetUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];
    SLRequest *tweetRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                 requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                           URL:getTweetUrl
                                                    parameters:nil];
    tweetRequest.account = theAccount;
    [tweetRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
            NSArray *fetchedTweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
            block(fetchedTweets, jsonParsingError);
        }
    }];
}
```

Next, add a property of type `ACAccount` to your second `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic) ACAccount *account;
```

Then, somewhere within your first table view controller you would have

```
//...
ACAccount *theAccount = ////this is initialized somehow within this class (the first UITableViewController subclass), probably by the selection of a row
SecondTableViewController *tweetsTableViewController = //initialize the table view controller
tweetsTableViewController.account = theAccount;
//...
```

Then, within your second `UITableViewController` subclass (probably within `-viewDidLoad`), you would have

```
    //...
    [TwitterWrapper fetchTweetsWithAccount:self.account completion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
        if (tweets) {
            self.tweets = tweets;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (error) {
            //present a UIAlertView, perhaps...
        }
    }];
    //...
```

Comment: Wow..first of all want to thank you for the reply and attention.little doubt: the "Tweets" is equal to "fetchedTweets" .. and gave an error n (NSError *, NSArray *) block

Comment: Yeah, use one of the approaches.  The last one is the best choice in this case, from what you've said about what you're doing.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking (little doubt: the "Tweets" is equal to "fetchedTweets"), yes.  The variable `fetchedTweets` in the handler block passed to `performRequestWithHandler:` refers to the same `NSArray` as the variable `tweets` in the completion block passed to `fetchTweetsWithCompletion:` (and `fetchTweetsWithAccount:completion:`).

Comment: I tested the method (using an account without value, only initialized). and the array is null

Comment: I mentioned four different approaches.  Which did you test?

Comment: You used a global variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using an account without value, only initialized".

Comment: I used, but it gave an error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_twitterAccount", referenced from:
      +[Fetcher fetchTweetsWithCompletion:] in Fetcher.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I fixed the code that was causing the error.  The variable `twitterAccount` needs to be defined, not just declared `extern`.  Add the line `ACAccount *twitterAccount;` to `TwitterWrapper.m` before the `@implementation` block.

Comment: Did you set `twitterAccount` from within your first table view controller?  You need to set it to the account that is selected before displaying the second table view controller.

Comment: Sorry but which method (UITableView) have to match the account (accounts [indexPath]) the variable of NSObject

Comment: 1view not recognize the TwitterAccount of NSObject

Comment: That's hard for me to know without seeing more code.  You need to set the global variable to be the account that is selected in the first table view before showing the second table view controller.  Otherwise, when `fetchTweetsWithCompletion:` is called, it will set `tweetRequest.account` to `nil` rather than to the account that is selected in the first table view.

Comment: is possible to have another kind of contact with you (to show the code in detail)

Comment: Sure.  Do you use IRC?  freenode.net #iphonedev would be a good place to continue this conversation.

Comment: Did you `#import` the appropriate file (`TwitterWrapper.h`) into your first table view controller's implementation file?

Comment: Sure, who should I add on iMessage?

Comment: I add you? is that I have little problems with the account (not recognized)

Comment: How about we use gmail chat instead?

Comment: nate.chandler.stackoverflow@gmail.com

Comment: send me an email, and we'll get this figured out.