# How to send a text to a label in another viewcontroller in xcode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, label

I'm new to the xcode and i cant say i know very much about it and here's my problem. I'm trying to set a text in a label from a tableViewController to a ViewController but explanation.label setText:@"blabla" doesnt appear to be work i get a blank screen. Label is in the VC.

i dont know if it's clear enough for you to be able to help but i'm stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: Ya.. you are right... this is not enough information...

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the variable `public` so other obj-c files can "see" it. Be sure your views `#import` each other, and check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081245/global-variables-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

First store the data in FirstTableViewController.m :

```
NSUserDefaults *x = [NSUSerDefaults standardUserDefaults ];
[x setObject : "putyourtext/yourselectedindexpath"] forKey : @"giveaname"];
```

Then u call the data in the other controller SecondViewController.m :

```
NSUserDefaults *x = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *mystring = [x stringForKey:@"giveaname"];

self.nameLabel.text = mystring;
```