# How do you declare a global variable in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, global-variables, global

I have just started to create my first iOs application with xcode.

How can I initialise and access a variable from anywhere in the application?

For example. I want to pass a BASE url *'http://www.repetitiveurl.com'*. to many of my added classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081245/global-variables-in-xcode?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constants in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

declare a variable in any .h file (outside the @interface)

and import the .h file in the class you wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer.

This isn't a very straightforward way, but it is the right way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/539191/1891327

Answer (score 0):

Both given answers are correct, i just add my answer to give another option to solve your "problem":

You could declare the variable in the `AppDelegate.h`, it depends on the variable and the use cases if this is a good idea. (usually it is not, but for some cases it is ok)